# IIS 7 X509 Certificate Issue

Tags: security, ssl, iis-7, x509, certificate

I am building a site that needs to call a 3rd party web service over https. The service requires an X509 certificate for authentication.

I can successfully call the service and get a response back using a console application, or a web application running in visual studio web server, this suggests to me that the code, and certificate provided by the 3rd party are all ok.

As soon as I deploy the site in IIS, it cannot connect to the service, I am getting "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error. I spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out, assuming it was permissions related as IIS app pool running under network service etc.

The certificate is installed in the local machine store, not current user, and I have granted network service (also added everyone is desperation!) using the winhttpcertcfg tool and manually in MMC > Manage Private Keys, so I am confident that the network service account has access to the certificate.

I also used the FindPrivateKey tool and checked the physical windows file and permissions look ok! I tried using identity impersonate in the config, using my windows account and that doesn't make a difference.

I am pulling my hair out with this one, can anyone give me any suggestions on what to try next?

Cheers

Comment: Did you take a wireshark?Is there are handshake request to the web service and is it aborted by the web service?Or the error is without even trying to contact the service?